# How can I convert from java ArrayList object to real value

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to get a value from the databae.

My Database query:

```
String GroupID1="select idCompanies from companies where Company_Name='ACME';";
```

here I'm calling to a javabeans which give back an ArrayLIst with one element

```
ArrayList<?> IdGroup1=oper.getList(GroupID1);
```

then, I print the result:

```
System.out.println(IdGroup1);
```

The query works fine, however I'm getting as a result:

```
[javabeans.ListOneElement@609f6e68]
```

Instead of the real value. How can I convert the java object to the real value?

Comment: What is 'real' value? What types does ArrayList returned by oper.getList() contain?

Comment: Do you have  more  of the code? Can you write a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1):

you are printing the `ArrayList` object `IdGroup1`,You need to iterate to get the alues

Comment: Sorry but I dont undestand. Yes, that's right. I'm printing the objects IdGroup1. But my intention is to print the real value which is "8". I'm trying with System.out.println(IdGroup1.get(0)); & System.out.println(IdGroup1.toString()); but it doesn't work.

Comment: It means that, I still receiving the java object javabeans.ListOneElement@6cddc0ca instead of the value.

Answer (score 1):

This code will retrieve the first (and only) item from the list:

```
System.out.println(IdGroup1.get(0).toString());
```

Adding the following will prevent a nullPointerException:

```
if (!IdGroup1.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(IdGroup1.get(0).toString());
```

-Added `.toString()` to get the value of the object

Comment: It's giving me back javabeans.ListOneElement@41ccdc4d which is the first objects within the ArrayLIst but not the ral value of the object in the database which is "8".

Comment: I added ".toString()" as one of the other posters mentioned, although depending on the structure of your object, there may be another method

Comment: @MaineCoder I fear there may indeed be another method.

Comment: Well, I would question why a list is being passed rather than just the object itself, since there is only one object (as stated in the question). But as @Pureferret hinted, you should really look at the object being passed from your bean and see how to extract the data. There should be a method that returns the info you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what type of Object `oper.getList(GroupID1)` will return.

You need to accommodate for whatever object that is and then convert it to String.

You need to:

1. Unpackage your list (that is a list contains, and is expected by java to possibly contain *multiple* objects, so it doesn't automatically 'unpack' it for you if you have a list of 1 object)
2. Extract your string. Here java might cleverly convert a number (int, float, etc. ) to a string for you.

For part two, look at what you expect the object to be by finding the JavaDocs for whatever package is handling your database queries. Then see how to extract your string.

It might be as simple as `System.out.println(IdGroup1.get(0).toString());`
Where `get(0)` unpackages the object from the list, and `toString()` extracts the string.

If you still get back `javabeans.ListOneElement@41ccdc4d` try other methods to extract your string....`toValue()` perhaps? It depends on the packages you're using.